VBA Option button "other" jumps to textbox
I have a UserForm1 with options why the discount is applied. One option is "Other".
I would like to "jump" into the Textbox associated with the Option button OptionO and vice versa: If user clicks and writes text, then OptionO is automatically set to true.

What code do I need to write?

SetFocus for Option button click and Change for textbox does the trick:
Private Sub OptionO_Click()
    Me.TextO.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub TextO_Change()
    Me.OptionO.Value = True
End Sub


Why would you want to set focus to the Text Box when you deselect the option?

Do you mean: add a if clause if clicking into/off it? It doesn't set focus if I click OptionA after OptionO was selected beforehand, so it seemed to me that it only sets focus when clicked onto it.
